# Convert java.util.stream.Stream to Scala Stream

Tags: scala, collections, scala-collections

I know how I can use the Java libraries, and I can write some loops that do the stuff I need for me, but the question is more, why is there nothing in `scala.collection.JavaConverters` or `scala.collection.JavaConverstions` to convert a `java.util.stream.Stream` to a `scala.collection.immutable.Stream`?

I would like to do something like this:

```
def streamFiles(path: Path): Stream[Path] = {
    Files.newDirectoryStream(path).asScala
}
```

But instead I have to write something like this:

```
def streamFiles(path: Path): Stream[Path] = {
  val path_it : java.util.Iterator[Path] = Files.newDirectoryStream(path).iterator()
  def loop(it: java.util.Iterator[Path]): Stream[Path] =
    if( it.hasNext )
     it.next #:: loop(it)
    else
      Stream()
  loop(path_it)
}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Which Stream (Java 8 or Scala)? What is the problem here? What do you tried to do already?

Comment: the conversion of Java8 stream to a Scala stream. So both. I thought that would be clear.

Comment: It is not. Please, rewrite your question, preferably with some code related to what you want to achieve.

Comment: @marcospereira I added some code. I hope you are now very pleased with it and excited to give me a nice answer.

Comment: Answered because other users may also need such information.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The current version of `JavaConverters` and `JavaConversions` don't offer conversions between Java Stream and Scala Stream because of differences at roadmaps.

Java 8, the version where [`java.util.stream.Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) was introduced, was [released at Mar 2014](https://blogs.oracle.com/thejavatutorials/entry/jdk_8_is_released) while Scala 2.11.0 was [officially released at Apr 2014](http://scala-lang.org/news/2.11.0/). So there was no time to change Scala 2.11 plans to add better integration with Java 8 features. In fact, better support to Java 8 is planned for Scala 2.12 (see the [roadmap here](http://www.scala-lang.org/news/2.12-roadmap/) and also this [presentation from Adrian Moors](http://adriaanm.github.io/reveal.js/scala-2.12.html)).

But anyway, there is [scala-java8-compat](https://github.com/scala/scala-java8-compat), "a Java 8 compatibility kit for Scala" and there is also [experimental support in Scala 2.11](https://gist.github.com/adriaanm/892d6063dd485d7dd221).

Looking at your code, there is a relevant issue: [`Files.newDirectoryStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newDirectoryStream(java.nio.file.Path)) returns a [`DirectoryStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/DirectoryStream.html) which is not a sub interface of `java.util.stream.Stream`, but an [`Iterable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) instead. So, what you need is a way to convert an `Iterable` to a Scala `Stream`, if this is what you really want, and your code should be like:

```
import java.nio.file.Path
import java.nio.file.Files

import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

object Foo {
  def streamFiles(path: Path): Stream[Path] = {
    Files.newDirectoryStream(path).iterator().asScala.toStream
  }
}
```

But if you still want to convert a `java.util.stream.Stream` to Scala Stream, add [scala-java8-compat](https://github.com/scala/scala-java8-compat) version 0.8.0-RC3 or newer to your project (you may need to [add a new resolver to your build too](http://www.scalatest.org/supersafe#installation)) and then do something like:

```
import scala.compat.java8.StreamConverters._

val numbers: java.util.List[Int] = java.util.Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3)
numbers.stream().toScala[Stream]
```