# how to convert java stream to scala stream?

Tags: scala, stream, java-stream

want to iterate thru bidChoices list and map using scala, below is the java code. what to perform the same using scala.

```
private String generateRestBody(String baseUrl, String auctionId, String baseAuctionId, List<String> bidChoices) {
        return BODY_TEMPLATE.formatted(
                DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME.format(OffsetDateTime.now()),
                bidChoices.stream()
                        .map(slotNo -> SELECTION_URI_TEMPLATE.formatted(BASE_URL, AUCTION_ID, BASE_AUCTION_ID, slotNo))
                        .collect(Collectors.joining(","))).replaceAll("\n", "");
    }
```

Comment: What did you try so far? What issues did you get?

Comment: In Scala there are different flavors of streams: deprecated `Stream`, `LazyList`, fs2, akka-stream etc. Also Java code can be written in Scala.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38339440/how-to-convert-a-java-stream-to-a-scala-stream https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38486886/convert-java-util-stream-stream-to-scala-stream